# how to iterate though 5 rows from get Max per row of 4 columns and set value of a different column accordingly

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I have a `DataFrame`, i've made a subset df2 of 4 columns from df1 and create a list of 5 items containing max value from each row. Now depending on which column the max value for that row is in i.e column 1, 2, 3, 4, determines the int label i.e. 1, 2, 3, or 4 in the label column in df1.

The df2 is because some of the other columns not including those 4 have a higher value than the 4 to compare and obviously screws that up. Starting to think it should be a list or series?

**code**

```
df1= pd.DataFrame({'x_1': [xvalues[0][0], xvalues[0][1], xvalues[0][2], 
                          xvalues[0][3], xvalues[0][4]], 
                  'x_2': [yvalues[0][0], yvalues[0][1], yvalues[0][2], 
                          yvalues[0][3], yvalues[0][4]],
                  'True labels': [truelabels[0], truelabels[1], 
                               truelabels[2],truelabels[3], truelabels[4]],
                  'g11': [classifier1[0][0],classifier1[0][1],
                          classifier1[0][2],classifier1[0][3],
                          classifier1[0][4],],
                  'g12': [classifier1[1][0],classifier1[1][1],
                          classifier1[1][2],classifier1[1][3],
                          classifier1[1][4],],
                  'g13': [classifier1[2][0],classifier1[2][1],
                          classifier1[2][2],classifier1[2][3],
                          classifier1[2][4],],
                  'g14': [classifier1[3][0],classifier1[3][1],
                          classifier1[3][2],classifier1[3][3],
                          classifier1[3][4],],
                  'L1': [2, 5, 6, 7, 8],
                  'g21': [classifier2[0][0],classifier2[0][1],
                          classifier2[0][2],classifier2[0][3],
                          classifier2[0][4],],
                  'g22': [classifier2[1][0],classifier2[1][1],
                          classifier2[1][2],classifier2[1][3],
                          classifier2[1][4],],
                  'g23': [classifier2[2][0],classifier2[2][1],
                          classifier2[2][2],classifier2[2][3],
                          classifier2[2][4],],
                  'g24': [classifier2[3][0],classifier2[3][1],
                          classifier2[3][2],classifier2[3][3],
                          classifier2[3][4],],
                  'L2': [0, 0, 0, 0, 0],
                  'g31': [classifier3[0],classifier3[0],
                          classifier3[0],classifier3[0],
                          classifier3[0],],
                  'g32': [classifier3[1][0],classifier3[1][1],
                          classifier3[1][2],classifier3[1][3],
                          classifier3[1][4],],
                  'g33': [classifier3[2][0],classifier3[2][1],
                          classifier3[2][2],classifier3[2][3],
                          classifier3[2][4],],
                  'g34': [classifier3[3][0],classifier3[3][1],
                          classifier3[3][2],classifier3[3][3],
                          classifier3[3][4],],
                  'L3': [0, 0, 0, 0, 0],
                  'Assigned L':[1, 1, 1, 1,1]}, index =['Datapoint1', 'D2', 'D3', 
                                                        'D4', 'D5'])



df2= df1[['g11','g12','g13','g14']]
hdf = df2.max(axis = 1)

g11 = df1['g11'].to_list()
g12 = df1['g12'].to_list()
g13 = df1['g13'].to_list()
g14 = df1['g14'].to_list()



for item, label in zip(hdf, table['L1']):
    if hdf[item] in g11:
        df1['L1'][label] = labels[0]
        print(item, label)
    elif hdf[item] in g12:
        df1['L1'][label] = labels[1]
        print(item, label)
    elif hdf[item] in g13:
        df1['L1'][label] = labels[2]
        print(item, label)
    elif hdf[item] in g14:
        df1['L1'][label] = labels[3]
        print(item, label)
```

I have tried using `.loc`, `.at` but when it didn't work I just scrapped it and tried something else, maybe those approaches would be better? This is where I'm at so far.

The error is coming from the for loop for hdf, 
The issue i'm having is `"cannot do label indexing on <class 'pandas.core.indexes.base.Index'> with these indexers [0.0311272081] of <class 'float'>"`

**I don't think the other values in the data frame are relvant, its just there so people know I have made one. The 5 relavant columns in the dataframe are g11, g12, g13, g14 and L1.**

Comment: This code probably contains most of the relevant information, but as it depends on unknows data (`xvalues`, etc.), we cannot run it to reproduce the problem. And as you do not say what line is causing the error, I cannot help...

Comment: @SergeBallesta Forgive me Serge but the xvalues arent relvant are they? The bottom block is the issue. Checking a list of values to see which of the 4 columns its in. xvalues and yvalues arent in either column to be checked, they are just other values in the dataframe.

Comment: I never said that is was relevant. I just say that without a sample data, I cannot reproduce the error. As a wild guess `df1['L1'][label] = ...` may be the problem, because the normal way is `df1[label, 'L1'] = ...`

Comment: @Serge Bellesta: Can you show me an example then, the code to check a value in a list against the values in 4 columns of a dataframe and set a different column value accordingly? If you use arbitrary variables and values, my data frame doesn't matter.

Comment: No I cannot. I have to reproduce to be able to answer. Not that I do not want to, but pandas is rather sensitive, and I really have to test my code...

Comment: Ok so what do you need to help me? i'll upload the whole project with excel data file to Github if that'll help?

Comment: I probably do not need all that... I just need some rows (even with fake values) from `df1` and the values (or some values) from `table` to be able to run the problematic part of the code. Just make sure that the reduced sample exhibits the problem. That's what is called a [mcve] on SO ;-)